# Objective-C: Reading contents of a file into an NSString object doesn't convert unicode

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring, escaping

I have a file, which I'm reading into an NSString object using stringWithContentsOfFile. It contains Unicode for Japanese characters such as:

```
\u305b\u3044\u3075\u304f
```

which I believe is

```
せいふく
```

I would like my NSString object to store the string as the latter, but it is storing it as the former.

The thing I don't quite understand is that when I do this:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

It stores it as: \u305b\u3044\u3075\u304f.

But when I hardcode in the string:

```
NSString *myString = @"\u305b\u3044\u3075\u304f";
```

It correctly converts it and stores it as: せいふく

Does stringWIthContentsOfFile escape the Unicode in some way?  Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your file does not literally contain the sequence "backslash-u-3-0-5-b"? The file should contain せいふく if that's what you want to read in.

Comment: I think it's the way that you are saying; but unfortunately, I can't edit the file.  Is there a way to get \u305b instead of backslash-u-3-0-5-b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, dont know how feasible it is..

```
NSArray *unicodeArray = [stringFromFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\u"];
NSMutableString *finalString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
for (NSString *unicodeString in unicodeArray) {
    if (![unicodeString isEqualToString:@""]) {
        unichar codeValue;
        [[NSScanner scannerWithString:unicodeString] scanHexInt:&codeValue];
        NSString* betaString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&codeValue length:1]; 
        [finalString appendString:betaString];
    }
} 
//finalString should have せいふく
```

Comment: The initial testing of this seems to work!  I hope it'll work for everything.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In the file `\u305b\u3044\u3075\u304f` are just normal characters. So you are getting them in string. You need to save actual Japanese characters in the file. That is, store `せいふく` in file and that will be loaded in the string.

Comment: For my case, I am unable to edit the file to include the Japanese characters.  Is that the only way?

Comment: Not sure whether there is any other way. You can try to replace the \u**** substrings with actual unicode characters after loading from file. Not a very feasible solution, no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `\u305b` in an Objective-C string is in fact an instruction *to the compiler* to replace it with the actual UTF-8 byte sequence for that character. The method reading the file is not a compiler, and only reads the bytes it finds. So to get that character (officially called "code point"), your file must contain the actual UTF-8 byte sequence for that character, and not the symbolic representation `\u305b`.

It's a bit like `\x43`. This is, in your source code, four characters, but it is replaced by one byte with value 0x43. So if you write @"\x43" to a file, the file will not contain the four characters '\', 'x', '4', '3', it will contain the single character 'C' (which has ASCII value 0x43).